# Disabling/Deleting Products in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to disable products in Magento as they are currently not available from my manufacturers but I know they will come back next year. If I disable these products, will it create 404 errors?

How do I delete products without creating 404 errors?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just saying **Out of Stock**, so you will keep all links?

[image]

Comment: Not only links but stock history is preserved as well.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! I hadn't thought of that. What is the purpose of disabling products?

Comment: Remember to upvote if you like the answers and mark an answer as the correct answer for your question if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to disable the product in frontend.
You can refer the following article for more:
http://masteringmagento.com/2010/04/8-and-a-half-reasons-your-magento-products-dont-show-up-in-the-catalog/